# How to Map Java Type to TypeScript/javascript

Tags: java, typescript

I made a corresponding UI object as follows. Now the backend Target java object has a field like following. Is there any way i can define similar in Angular Target object.Is there set and Map object implementation in Angular2

#### Java

*Not javascript*

```
private Set<String> exportCodes = new HashSet<>();
private Map<String, Set<String>> itemDataTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

#### Corresponding TypeScript object

```
export class Target {
    constructor(
        public name?: string,
        public targetType?: string,
        public exportUrl?: string,
        public userName?: string,
        public password?: string,
    ) { }
}
```

Comment: Angular doesn't provide any collections. This is a pure TypeScript or JavaScript question.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking or trying to achieve... Can you please elaborate with additional detail or a more complete example?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : Ah okay. Thank you. So is there any prebuild collections in typescript ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what "rebuild collections" mean, but I'm not using TS actively myself.

Comment: @Igor : So basically how can i declare a Set in Target frontend class

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : I mean such as Java has collection package which Set is part of , are there any angular/typescript which define Set collection. Dont want to implement Set by my own.

Comment: The same as in javascript or in typescript, there is nothing special with adding a field to a class. I have no idea where `Set<string>` is coming from but whatever package declares that you need to import into your typescript file.

Comment: *(I think I figured out what you are asking?)* Are the top 2 lines c#, are you trying to map your c# types to typescript??

Comment: Yes . those are java type actually. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: For clarification: So you want to map `Java` types to `TypeScript`/`javascript` types.... ?

Comment: Yes You got me now. I researched but not able to see anything posted by anyone.

Comment: I updated your question, you could update it further to be more accurate. Please remember, we cannot guess what you are after you have to specify this in your question. At no point did you mention Java code or mapping of server side code to typescript. This is also completely outside of anything to do with Angular.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. So is there anything existing i can use :)

Comment: Okay i found in angular commons package and i defined like following public exportCodes?: Set<string>  and it gives no error on compiling. It has a Map implementation also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    I used. This works. tested
```

MAP

```
    interface Map
    var Map: MapConstructor
```

SET

```
    declare var Set: SetConstructor;
```

conversions might look like following. I still need to check with data.

```
    public exportCodes?: Set<string>,
    public itemDataTypeMap?: Map<string, Set<Item>>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) classes in ES6-enabled browsers, you should just need to set the `target` of your `tsconfig.json` to ES6.

There are also polyfills for old-school browsers. like [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)

You should then be able to declare such objects like:

```
let foo = new Map<string,Set<string>>();
let bar = new Set<string>();
```

Also note that the traditional way of creating a `Map<string,something>` in js is to make an object that will act as an associative array, it has the advantage of being portable across old and modern browsers. You can declare this in typescript like a dictionnary:

```
let foo:{[k:string]:any}={}
```